# Javascript Text Fields and PHP variable Declaration

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, textfield

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var skillctr = 1;
var experiencectr = 1;
var educationctr = 1;
var achievementctr = 1;
var historyctr = 1;

/*
Add Skills
*/ 

$("#addSkill").click(function () {

if(skillctr>10){
        alert("WOW! But 10 skills are enough.");
        return false;
}   

var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
     .attr("id", 'SkillDiv' + skillctr);

newTextBoxDiv.html('<label>Skill No. '+ skillctr + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="skill' + skillctr +
      '" id="skill' + skillctr + '" value="" >');

newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#SkillsBoxesGroup");


skillctr++;
 });
```

so how can i save the generated fields in my table in database now?
how am i gonna declare the field in php like.. $_POST['skill'].
i need help here. please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `name="skill' + skillctr + '"`, use `name="skill[]"`.
That way PHP will helpfully create an array that you can loop though:

```
var_dump($_POST);

foreach ($_POST['skill'] as $skill) {
    // save $skill to database
}
```

Comment: var_dump($_POST); ? where will i put that one? Inside <?php ?> tags?

Comment: my table is like this.. fields: user_id(auto_increment) | skill_01 | skill_02 | skill_03, but with your code it saved a row each.. and every skill has one row now with diff user_ids. Can you please help me @deceze?

Comment: @Jennifer Yes, that `var_dump` is just supposed to show you what you will receive in PHP. If this is all supposed to go into the same row, then this is probably not the right thing for you to do. Then I don't really know what the problem is though, you'll need to elaborate where you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks :) your answer is just what i've been looking for. you are a life saver! i made a new table for skills, so can i ask how to JOIN the table rows INTO just ONE FIELD. have any idea? please....

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure that the input elements you are adding with that javascript are inside a `<form>`. Then when you submit the form to a php page, you can access the values with `$_POST` like you wrote above.

Comment: nah it's inside the form. also the add skill and delete skill buttons are inside the form. When javascript generates the fields they are also inside the form. sigh, i've been doing this for three days now.